# Semantic-ui not using themes

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm completely at a dead end. I'm trying to customise my semantic-ui build using either the variables in `/site` or a custom theme in `/themes/mytheme` but neither appears to be working in any way shape or form.

**What I've tried:**

- Use `/site`

As a test, I've tried to override a variable in the `/site/collections/menu.variables` file which does not appear to be used. To confirm this, I placed completely invalid CSS (plain text) which should result in an error, and nothing:

```
@variable: "test";
I'm invalid CSS!!
```

This causes no error, and I'm left with a completely valid CSS output containing just the default definitions.

- Use `/themes/mytheme`

I created a new folder in `/themes` for the menu variables, specifically `/themes/mytheme/collections/menu.variables`. This file contains the same invalid CSS as above. I have then adjusted the `theme.config` file to contain the following:

```
...
/* Collections */
@breadcrumb : 'default';
@form       : 'default';
@grid       : 'default';
@menu       : 'mytheme';
@message    : 'default';
@table      : 'default';
```

Once again, there is no error when running `gulp build` and I am again left with a CSS file containing nothing but the default definitions.

My project structure is as follows:

```
semantic.json
semantic
  - src
    - definitions
    - site
    - themes
    - semantic.less
    - theme.less
    - theme.config
  - tasks
  - gulpfile.js
```

My semantic.json file contains:

```
{
  "base": "semantic/",
  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config": "src/theme.config",
      "definitions": "src/definitions/",
      "site": "src/site/",
      "themes": "src/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged": "dist/",
      "uncompressed": "dist/components/",
      "compressed": "dist/components/",
      "themes": "dist/themes/"
    },
    "clean": "dist/"
  },
  "permission": false,
  "autoInstall": false,
  "rtl": false,
  "components": [
  ...
  ],
  "version": "2.2.9"
}
```

I'm running node 7.6.0 (current latest) so upgrading node won't resolve anything (as I've seen other people have found a fix by updating node).

Any help would be massively appreciated, I'm really getting fed up of this now.

Answer (score 1):

Right, well it appears that it is in fact using the theme as expected, however there is absolutely no feedback when something goes wrong. Putting invalid CSS in my themes `site` file causes errors to appear, but in anything else it simply gets ignored and the defaults are used.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? any way to atleast find a log of errors in the `site` less files

Comment: Afraid I can't really remember what happened here but I don't recall ever finding any logs for it. I just fixed it and never had the issue again

Comment: Ok thanks. My issue was a bit different. If there is any error in the `site` files that have `.variables` or `.overrides` extension, the compiler would not show them. So it was very difficult to find out the issue. But I was able to fix that by using a simple `@import` in the `.overrides` file to include another file which has a `.less` extension, and now the compiler does show errors if there are any in the `.less` file. So basically it does not report errors if the file extension is NOT `.less`. Hope that helps someone.